# "Invalid maximum heap size" when running Maven

Tags: java, maven, jvm, heap-memory

I'm having problems setting up maven. I'm using windows 7 64 bit with 4 GB of RAM.

I get this error when trying to run mvn:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here are my user variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m

Path=%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Can you run java at all? Try `java -version` first. What happens?

Comment: Are you sure `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` doesn't contain strange characters? Perhaps the hyphen became an n-dash or something? Might have happened if you copy/pasted the example from somewhere.

Comment: @RobAu No such thing as "M3_HOME", it's just M2_HOME for all versions of Maven. See http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation

Comment: Really? Mine is set to "MAVEN_HOME", which works fine.

Comment: Since it's optional, what happens when you remove the MAVEN_OPTS altogether?

Comment: Do you have to put the options in quotes, e.g. `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"`?  There is a space between the options, perhaps Windows doesn't like that.

Comment: I resolved the same issue on windows executing this command on windows command line : set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

Comment: med_alpa comment helps me, quotes are ambiguous in Windows

Answer (score 4):

User @med_alpa had the right suggestion in my case (Windows):

> I resolved the same issue on windows executing this command on windows
>   command line : set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

So make sure to not put quotes around the value you set for MAVEN_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

alter jvm.config in .mvn directory ( it is in controller directory ).
study mvn.sh that comes with maven. you will see MAVEN_OPTS setting in the script. 
try out java  -version before altering. 
eg : java -Xmx512m -version
now you know how to go about and make the changes.

/sunil

Answer (score 0):

Try using: -Xmx1024M

**Note:** 'M' instead 'm'

Comment: Please add some explanation what is the difference and why should the OP do that.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS a version of [@adriaan-koster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181336/adriaan-koster)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51192416/1732222) works.

In your `~/.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) config file add this line:

```sh
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2G"
```

To test, run `mvn -v` again and verify that it prints the Maven version, Maven home location, and Java version.